# When "for each" loop returns nullptr for a item?

Tags: c++, c++11

I watched CppCon "Writing Good C++14... By Default" by Herb Sutter and on one of the slides was following piece of code:

```
auto p = make_shared<circle>(42);
auto v = load_shapes();
for(auto& s: v) {
  if(s && *s == *p) {
    cout << *s << "is a match\n";
  }
}
```

My question is: why there is a

> if(s && *s == *p)

check?

How can reference variable  initialized by *for each* loop be *nullptr* ? Loop iterates over items, so in which case *nullptr* value can be assigned ?

**EDIT**: 
My point of interest is what is this check for:

```
if(s)
```

When s is obtained by "for each", how it can be null?

Comment: Consider the type of `v` could be `std::vector<shape*>`.

Comment: It has absolutely nothing to do with references. When you use a reference you just use the variable it's bound to, you don't use "the reference variable". So in this code the objects in `v` can be converted to bool. The fact the code uses a reference is irrelevant.

Comment: `using namespace std;` is not good code - this is implied in this example

Comment: but isn't a "s" reference?

Comment: So what if it's a reference? You need to know what it's a reference **to**, not care that it's a reference.

Comment: But a reference to what? Could be a reference to a pointer to a piece of pizza.

Comment: what means " if (s)" ?? what is this check for?

Comment: @EdHeal, maybe the using directive is immediately above the example, in function scope, in which case saying it's "not good code" is nonsense.

Comment: @Wiertek, presumably it's checking for a valid pointer. You can write `int* s = some_function(); if (s) { }`, and you can also write `int*& r = s; if (r) { }`. The reference is irrelevant. What matters is what it's a reference **to**.

Comment: @JonathanWakely - I think that habits are a good thing. Like putting `std::` in front of `make_shared` for example. The scope of the code may expand in the future - who is to know?

Comment: @EdHeal: The question states this is from a slide. Talking about coding best practices off of a slide is a bit pointless. I would omit `std::` on a slide as well, because unlike my real code where long-term maintainability is an important goal, on a slide my biggest constraint is visual space.

Comment: @Wiertek: `s` can be a pointer. `if (s)` is equivalent to `if (s != nullptr)`.

Comment: @GManNickG Thanks, I get this but how a loop can return nullptr? It iterates over items, one by one on a collection, so if there is no item it does not return anything, isn't it?

Comment: The items are pointers, so those items can be null. Like I said in the first comment.

Comment: @EdHeal, maybe the function says `using std::make_shared; using std::cout;` -- is that bad too? You're making a lot of assumptions when you say it implies bad code, so the comment is simply irrelevant and unhelpful here. There simply isn't enough context to make such sweeping generalizations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume the following definitions.

```
struct circle {
    circle(int r) :radius(r) {}
    int radius;

    bool operator==(circle rhs) const {
        return radius == rhs.radius;
    }
};

std::vector<circle*> load_shapes() {
    std::vector<circle*> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        vec.push_back(nullptr);
    return vec;
}
```

With that, I can now insert the example code into a main function:

```
int main() {
    using namespace std;
    auto p = make_shared<circle>(42);
    auto v = load_shapes();
    for(auto& s: v) {
      if(s && *s == *p) {
        cout << *s << "is a match\n";
      }
    }
}
```

With that definition for `load_shapes`, `v` (in main) is of type `std::vector<circle*>`, it has 10 elements, all of them null pointers. So in the for loop, `s` is of type `circle*&` (reference to pointer to circle). And in each iteration, the pointer it refers to is a null pointer. That's what the if statement is checking for.

Note that there are of course other possible definitions. For example, `load_shapes` could return `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<shape>>`, where `shape` is a base class of `circle` (and I suspect that is exactly what the slide author had in mind).